# ActiveMQ network of brokers messages are not balanced

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using **ActiveMQ 5.13.4** and I have set up a `network-of-brokers` with two brokers `A` and `B` that are connected via a `networkConnector`. Each broker has a consumer connected to it (`A'` and `B'`). `A'` and `B'` consume messages from the same `distributed queue` (e.g. `requests-queue`). Each consumer is a java application, represented by a Spring `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` having the setting `concurrency: 5-10`. Basically, each consumer has max 10 threads that can consume simultaneously messages from the queue.

In broker configuration (`activemq.xml`) I have set the prefetch size to 1, assuming that there are not many messages and they need a lot of processing time.

`<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" optimizedDispatch="true" queuePrefetch="1" enableAudit="false">`

The **desired behavior** is when I send 100 messages to `A` it starts processing 10 messages simultaneously (one for each consumer thread) and forwards another 10 to `B`. When `B` finishes processing the first 10 messages, it would get an extra 10. This would continue until all the messages are processed.

The **actual behavior** is that when I send 100 messages to `A`, it sends 10 messages, one per each thread, to the local consumer `A'` and forwards the remaining 90 to `B'`. The consumers on `A'` finish processing the messages and they wait while 90 messages get processed on broker `B` by its consumers.

**Question:** How can I configure the network in order to balance messages based on consumer availability?

The full `activemq.xml` configuration for one of the brokers is the following. The other one has the same configuration only a different name and IP in the networkConnector.

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            brokerName="broker-jms-tux-01-qa-gnd"
            persistent="false"
            dataDirectory="${activemq.data}"
            cacheTempDestinations="false"
            advisorySupport="true"
            useJmx="true">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                        <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                             slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                             by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                             For more information, see:

                             http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                        -->
                        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                        <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                            <vmCursor/>
                        </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    </policyEntry>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" optimizedDispatch="true" queuePrefetch="1" enableAudit="false">
                        <!--
                        Allow messages to be replayed back when the broker to which they were forwarded does not have any more consumers.
                        See section "Stuck Messages" from http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html
                        -->
                        <networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                            <!--
                            N.B.: When using replayWhenNoConsumers=true for versions < 5.9, it is necessary to also disable the cursors duplicate detection using enableAudit=false as the cursor could mark the replayed messages as duplicates (depending on the time window between playing and replaying these messages over the network bridge). The problem is fully explained here: http://tmielke.blogspot.de/2012/03/i-have-messages-on-queue-but-they-dont.html
                            -->
                            <conditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory replayWhenNoConsumers="true"/>
                        </networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                        <pendingQueuePolicy>
                            <vmQueueCursor/>
                        </pendingQueuePolicy>
                        <deadLetterStrategy>
                            <sharedDeadLetterStrategy expiration="300000"/>
                        </deadLetterStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!-- Network of brokers -->
        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector
                    name="broker-jms-tux-01-qa-gnd->broker-jms-tux-02-qa-gnd"
                    uri="static:(tcp://10.83.16.22:61616)"
                    conduitSubscriptions="false"
                    dynamicOnly="true"
                    networkTTL="2"
                    alwaysSyncSend="true"
                    decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                    duplex="false"/>
        </networkConnectors>
        <!--
          The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
          use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
          http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="80"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="4 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 400MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=3200000000"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook"/>
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Thanks you in advance!

**Update 25/10/2016: **
I have come across the following statement in: http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

> The conditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory factory allows a rate limit
>   to be specified for a destination, such that network consumer can be
>   throttled. Prefetch for a network consumer is largely negated by the
>   fact that a network consumer relays a message typically acks very
>   quickly so even with a low prefetch and decreased priority a network
>   consumer can starve a modestly quick local consumer. Throttling
>   provides a remedy for this.

**Question:** It is still not clear for me, why when the local consumer A' finishes processing the initial 10 messages, broker A does not receive any of the 80 messages remaining on B (because 10 were dispatched to the local consumer of broker B)?

I have tried setting a higher `networkTTL`, but it still does not work.

Comment: Your solution sounds like distributed consumption or what is typically meant by "clustering". Store-and-forward is when a broker forwards _all_ messages to a second broker for processing.   

Out of the box, the network connectors do a good job of distributing consumers across the network. You have a lot of tuning and additional configuration that I would suggest backing out all the "extra" stuff and make sure the message flow works first. "failover" may have been removed as an option, since a network connector auto-reconnects anyway. I'd remove vmCursor and the networkBridgeFilterFactory.

Comment: Currently, the "message flow" works as described in the initial post. You might be right about the configurations. ActiveMQ tends to provide tons of configuration on many levels (broker, consumer, destination, etc.) that might conflict with one another. I actually did try stripping off all the "extra" stuff, but the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: I do have a feeling where is the issue coming from, but I am not aware how to fix it. Due to the fact that I have set **queuePrefetch="1"**, the local consumers don't receive any extra requests until they did not acknowledge the one that they are processing. Contrary, the remote broker acknowledges messages not when they are sent to remote consumers, but immediately after storing them locally. Maybe there is a way to make the remote broker accept new messages only when his consumers are idle?

Comment: Try lowering the networkConnector prefetch to "1" or some number lower than the 1000 default value. <networkConnector.. prefetchSize="1" ..

Comment: It seems I have found the answer [here](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html). I still need to figure out what represents **rateLimit**.
_The conditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory factory allows a rate limit to be specified for a destination, such that network consumer can be throttled. Prefetch for a network consumer is largely negated by the fact that a network consumer relays a message typically acks very quickly so even with a low prefetch and decreased priority a network consumer can starve a modestly quick local consumer. Throttling provides a remedy for this._